# Expectation of a generalized real-valued Brownian motion

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a real-valued Brownian motion on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$, $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ and $$\langle W,\phi\rangle:=\int_{[0,\infty)}\phi(t)B_t\;{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }\phi\in\mathcal D:=C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)\;.$$ Note that $\phi B(\omega,\;\cdot\;)$ is $\lambda$-integrable over $[0,\infty)$ for almost every $\omega\in\Omega$, since $B$ is almost surely continous and $\operatorname{supp}\phi$ is compact for all $\phi\in\mathcal D$.

> I would like to change the order of integration in $$\operatorname E[W](\phi):=\operatorname E\left[\langle W,\phi\rangle\right]\;\;\;\text{for }\phi\in\mathcal D$$ in order to obtain (using $B_t\sim\mathcal N_{0,t}$) $$\operatorname E[W](\phi)=\int_{[0,\infty)}\phi(t)\underbrace{\operatorname E\left[B_t\right]}_{=0}\;{\rm d}\lambda=0\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in\mathcal D\;.$$

Let's assume that $B$ is (surely) continuous. Then (by continuity) $\phi B$ is $\operatorname P\otimes\lambda$-measurable and it remains to show that $\phi B\in\mathcal L^1(\operatorname P\otimes\lambda)$ for all $\phi\in\mathcal D$. After that we can change the order of integration by *Fubini's theorem*. So, how do we show that?

Can we obtain the result without the additional assumption of sure continuity, i.e. if $B$ is only almost surely continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is continuous with compact support, it suffices to show that for each $R$, 
$$\mathbb E\left[\int_{[0,R]}|B_t
|\mathrm d\lambda(t)\right]$$
is finite. By Schwarz inequality, it suffices to check finiteness of 
$$I:=\mathbb E\left[\int_{[0,R]}B_t^2\mathrm d\lambda(t)\right].$$
Using Fubini-Tonnelli theorem (that is, switching integral *when the integrand is non-negative*) and noticing that $\mathbb E\left[B_t^2\right]=t$, we get finiteness of $I$.

Comment: I've edited question slightly cause I made a mistake. I've said that $\phi B$ would be product measurable by continuity, but that's not true cause $B$ is only almost surely continuous. We need the product measurability in order to apply Fubini's theorem. Can we prove the result without the additional assumption (made in the question)? I don't think so.

Comment: I want to note that this led me to the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633453/why-do-people-all-the-time-exploiting-almost-sure-properties-of-a-stochastic-pro