# Why do people all the time exploiting almost sure properties of a stochastic process as if they were sure properties?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

All the time, I see people working with a *given* Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ on a *fixed* probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and suddenly exploiting its almost sure properties as if they were sure properties.

Yeah, I know we can find a $\operatorname P$-null set $N\subseteq\Omega$ such that these properties hold surely on $\tilde\Omega:=\Omega\setminus N$ and hence coud replace $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ by $(\tilde\Omega,\left.\mathcal A\right|_{\tilde\Omega},\left.\operatorname P\right|_{\tilde\Omega})$. As a second option, we can modify $X_t$ on $N$ for any $t\ge 0$ such that these properties hold surely on $\Omega$.

However, either we need to modify the probability space or the Brownian motion. But that's a weird and unusual practice in mathematics.

If we can't prove the desired result, then we just modify our objects such that we can prove them. *Carry the world as you like it*.

Shouldn't we better state (in a theorem) that there *exists* $B$ and $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ such that ... instead of fixing $B$ and $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ (at a global space)?

And that's just an example. In probability theory, we do things like that all the time. Why is it legitimate?

Comment: It is certainly legitimate as long as each claim contains the notorious *a.s.* "disclaimer".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That would be fine, but that's not why I mean. For example, there are many textbooks where the authors prove that the expecation $$\operatorname E[W]:\mathcal D\to\mathbb R\;,\;\;\;\phi\mapsto\operatorname E\left[\langle W,\phi\rangle\right]$$ of a generalized Brownian motion $$\langle W,\phi\rangle:=\int \phi(t)B_t\;{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }\phi\in\mathcal D:=C_c^\infty([0,\infty))$$ is $0$. They do it using Fubini's theorem. But we cannot apply the theorem unless $B$ is jointly measurable, which cannot be assumed unless $B$ is surely continuous.

Comment: "Why is it legitimate?" It's not legitimate, it's sloppy.  Harmless most of the time, but sloppy.